# Delphi plugin for pasting text constants in source code?

Tags: delphi, ide, editor

Inserting (pasting from clipboard) of text constants in the Delphi code editor requires some manual "postprocessing" ...

- split up long text into multiple lines (and  insert the string concatenation symbol)
- escape quotes (replace single quotes with double quotes)
- enclose the string with quotes
- keep original white space (leading blanks, line feeds)

Is there a IDE plugin available which helps to reduce these manual steps?

Comment: CnWizards has a basic selected text block conversion (select text in editor and go to menu *CnPack / Code Editor Wizard / Convert to String*). Unfortunately doesn't know to split the lines (maybe there's a way to configure it, don't know).

Comment: Castalia also has this feature, minus splitting long lines. It's called Multipaste. http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/other.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://roschinspb.narod.ru/develop.html#PasteSpecial) expert (sorry for russian, there is a gif that shows what it can do)